# Files disappeared, no trace

Tags: macos

Yesterday, my wife imported 350 images from her camera's SD card from her sister's wedding (thus, quite important images), and as we have BackBlaze installed on her macbook for cloud backup, we have been able to confirm via. the backblaze interface that at least about 50 of them have been backed up to backblaze, which means that they must have been on the computer as backblaze does not back up files from external sources.

We have tried with local Time Machine (but the disk only has 20GB left, so Time Machine didn't have much), Disk Drill to see if they were deleted, but haven't found them yet (Disk Drill is still running), and they are not in the trash neither. Neither of us have had the terminal opened, so it shouldn't be a rouge terminal command either.

Disk Drill on the SD card is not an option, as they have since been overwritten sadly.

We have more or less given up on getting the images back, but we still can't figure out how the files could disappear with no trace like this. If anyone has any ideas about what we could do, please let us know.

Comment: There are 1000 reasons why a drive can die. Two primary categories. Physical issues / Logical Issues. At any rate, you might try PhotoRec it works on SD cards, I have had success with this in the past.  https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: It's not the whole drive though - Other files in the same folder are there, and we haven't gotten any issues with the SSD in the macbook. I will check the SSD now though, just to make sure it's not an upcoming drive failure.

Comment: If they were there long enough for BackBlaze to upload 50 of them, they should have been there long enough for Time Machine to copy them. Did you check back far enough? Did you check they were all there immediately after the import?

Comment: @Tetsujin: We checked time machine, but it was only locally on the macbook itself, and since it was low on disk space, time machine only had the last 1-2 hours, not all the way back to the morning where we believe they disappeared. We did check that they were all there after import (verified the number of images as well as the name of the first and last image in the import)